# Magento 2: Add the Logout button in Customer My Account

Tags: magento2

How can I add the Logout link in Customer My Account using the authorization-link in the body of ../Magento_Customer/layout/customer_account.xml?

I want to add this block:

to customer_account.xml to show logout link in my account, in main column of this view, the bottom of all

Answer (score 2):

you can try this to add a tab in the customer account:

> ```
>         <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\SortLinkInterface" name="name of the block">
>             <arguments>
>                 <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">your path eg: abc/abc</argument>
>                 <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">name of the tab</argument>
>                 <argument name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">52</argument>
>             </arguments>
>         </block>
> ```

Answer (score 1):

You can add the Logout link by adding below block in your `customer_account.xml` file after all links.

```
<referenceBlock name="customer_account_navigation">
    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="demo-link">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">customer/account/logout</argument>
            <argument name="label" xsi:type="string">LogOut</argument>
            <argument name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">1000</argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>
</referenceBlock>
```

Hope it helps!!!